# Trigger when youtube video finished

Tags: jquery, youtube, addeventlistener

Following is my code.

```
<object width="620" height="327">
    <param name="movie" value="http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/0s5lxs7Xvu8?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&rel=0"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/0s5lxs7Xvu8?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&rel=0" id="video1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" width="620" height="327" onended="videoEnded()"></embed>
</object>
```

I want to display an alert message when the video comes to end. Can you please help me on this. Need to do it in jQuery

Comment: I added following code.
player.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(state){
    if(state === 0){
        // the video is end, do something here.
    }
});
But its not working

Comment: Have you changed over to using the JS API to embed the video? At the moment your code is using HTML embedding.

Answer (score 0):

you need to listen to the onStateChange event, catch that and see if the state change event tells you that the song has finished.

```
new YT.Player("yt_element", {
    videoId: your_video_id,
    .. height with etc ....
    , events: {
        'onStateChange': function(event){
            if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
                ... show the song ended alert ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it says ReferenceError: YT is not defined

Comment: did you follow the instructions on how to embed here? it sounds like you just have an embedded iframe there https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player